# Why can't set "defaultTextFormat" directly?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

for example,we can set graphics of a shape directly(without creating an external Graphics variable):

```
var my_shape:Shape=new Shape();
my_shape.graphics.beginFill(0);
```

but that's not same as defaultTextFormat
 the below code doesn't work:

```
var my_text:TextField=new TextField();
my_text.defaultTextFormat.size=47;
```

typing dot after defaultTextFormat,the code hint of text format appears and there is no compiler error but still doesn't work
we must create an external TextFormat variable:

```
var my_text:TextField=new TextField();
var my_format:TextFormat=new TextFormat();
my_format.size=47;
my_text.defaultTextFormat=my_format;
```

but why can't set directly?
I don't like a lot of variables.
after that,explain the difference between textFormat and Graphics.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a very important question.I wonder why it isn't rated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access/read a TextField's `defaultTextFormat` property (which is what's happening in the line  `my_text.defaultTextFormat.size=47;`), you end up getting a whole new object returned. Eg, it creates a new TextFormat and returns that.

Here is an example to illustrate:

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textField.defaultTextFormat = tf;
trace(tf == textField.defaultTextFormat) //false
```

The `TextField` doesn't know anything about the `TextFormat` it returns from `defaultTextFormat`. So when you change it, it doesn't update anything automatically because it has no scope inside the TextField that generated it.

> In order to see the change, you have to reassign the whole object, and
>   then reassign the text (if you've already set the text).

This unfortunately means you'll have do it like in your second example.

It's probably some kind of an efficiency thing under the hood to help prevent memory leaks and the like.

Here are some examples to consider further:

```
var txt:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(txt);
var tf:TextFormat;

txt.text = "hi"; //default formatting;

tf = txt.defaultTextFormat; //get the default formatting, which actually returns a brand new object
tf.color = 0xFF0000; //make it red;

//nothing has changed visually

txt.defaultTextFormat = tf; //this won't update it either

//nothing has changed visually

txt.text = txt.text; //now that we've 'changed' the text, you'll see red
```

Comment: Someone care to explain the down vote? If there is some error, please point it out.

Answer (score -2):

```
my_text.defaultTextFormat = my_format;
```

my_format is the defaultTextFormat of your textField my_text. `defaultTextFormat` is a property of your `TextField` (which value is my_format).

```
my_format.size = 47;
```

47 is the size of your  TextFormat my_format. `size` is a property of your `TextFormat` (which value is 47).

```
my_text.defaultTextFormat.size = 47;
```

...but `size` has never been a property of a `defaultTextFormat`.

> So you cannot put properties directly on the defaultTextFormat. What
>   you need to do is to make a text format, set the properties, THEN set
>   defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat.

Adobe help about [defaultTextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#defaultTextFormat).

Comment: That's the correct answer. 3 votes down from 3 `BAD` coders. Size isn't, HAS NEVER BEEEN a property of defaultTextFormat.

Comment: I'm not sure how this even answers the question, nevermind being the 'correct' answer?   `defaultTextFormat` returns a text format, which in turn has a `size` property.  `trace(textField.defaultTextFormat.size)` will trace out the size of the text fields text format.

Comment: Using my_text.`defaultTextFormat.size` is a very bad coding practice. The fact that somebody try to do it isn't a reason to encourage it. Adobe help describe simply how to use TextField, TextFormat and defaultTextFormat. That's sufficient. Ask HITMAN to put here his final code using `defaultTextFormat.size`... I will show it's not useful and a very bad practice.

Comment: Nobody is (or has been) arguing about trying to set properties on defaultTextFormat.   @HITMAN already knows it doesn't work that way,  he wants to know why.

Comment: @LDMS He tries that because he hasn’t read the Adobe help, and the reason why this doesn’t work is simple: wanting to set the size of a textFormat without having created it is of course impossible! (`my_text.defaultTextFormat.size = 47;`) He thinks that defaultTextFormat is a TextFormat, when (tf =) my_text.defaultTextFormat is a TextFormat. If he wants to get it after the textFormat was created, he can get the size of my_text.defaultTextFormat, but it’s much more simple and a better (normal) practice to call directly tf. Thats why I say that size has never been a property of defaultTextFormat